# Undefined array key 0 siendo que existe

Tags: php, laravel, array, api

Estoy trabajando con una api de prestashop donde vienen en algunos casos 2 o mas arrays

el tema es que al llamar al array de la posicion cero y utilizar un dd, este me muestra el valor de esta posicion, pero al momento de quitarlo y hacer que se guarde, me retorna el ErrorException `Undefined array key 0`

```
 }else if (count($array) >= 1 ){
                    //dd("Hay 2 array o mas");
                    $resourceId = $array['address'][0]['id_customer'];
                    $resourceDni = $array['address'][0]['dni'] ? : 'Sin Rut';
                    $resourcePhone = $array['address'][0]['phone'] ? : 'Sin numero';
                    //dd($resourcePhone);
                    $neworder = Customer::updateOrCreate(
                        ['prestashop_id' => $resourceId],
                        [
                            'dni' => $resourceDni,
                            'telephone' => $resourcePhone
                            ]
                        );
                    //dd($array);                    
                }
```

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

La verdad no entiendo por que me dice Undefined Key 0, siendo que si existe dentro del array, yo solo necesito tomar los valores de esta posicion del array 0 y almacenarla, no necesito la de la posicion 1... como o que debo corregir dentro del codigo, probe con `$array['address'][1]['id_customer'];` pero es el mismo problema

Comment: No tiene sentido, conforme a lo que muestras está bien. Alguna tontería se está escapando, o falta información, o quizá el *Undefined array key 0* corresponde a otro punto.

Comment: En la estructura que muestras ese código no debería dar ese error. Revisa bien el mensaje de error, debería decir el archivo y la línea en que ocurre, pues a veces el error ocurre en otra parte, no en la que uno se imagina. También puede ser un problema de caché, que esté usando una versión antigua del archivo donde sí existía el error...

Comment: La función `dd()` detiene la ejecución (dump and die), posiblemente, si el código se repite, no sea en la primer ejecución que el array no tiene el índice 0, pero el dd detiene la ejecución a la primer pasada

Comment: podrías agregar la salida de  `var_dump($array);`